# "He carried a gun for _____ "?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm reading an English story written by an Italian student, and there's a line which says

> 1. Mark carried a gun in his briefcase for **safety reasons**

Now, when talking to him earlier I understood what he meant. The hero of his story placed the gun in his briefcase, in case he needed to use it. The gun was for his own personal safety.

I suppose **self defence** could have been used, but it suggests that the hero knew what was lying in store for him.

I suggested,

> 2. Mark carried a gun **on the off chance** that he needed to use it.

But Cambridge Dictionary says

> **[off chance](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/off-chance)** *noun*
>   hoping that something may be possible, although it is not likely:

Which changes the story somewhat, and besides which, the phrase becomes  too clumsy sounding.

Does ‘precaution measures’ sound better?

> 3. Mark carried a gun for **precaution** measures

CD defines it as

> **[precaution](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/precaution)** *noun*
>   an action that is done to prevent something unpleasant or dangerous happening

Is there a pithier, an easier expression or phrase that people use when they fear they *might* face danger?

Context: Mark placed the gun with the $100,000 cash that was in his briefcase. In the end, the "hero" never needed to use the gun.

Comment: *Precautionary measures* is idiomatic, as opposed to *precaution measures*. I'm addressing this issue only, not answering your question.

Comment: "On the chance" may be better than "on the off chance" here; "off chance" suggests something less than mortal danger. To be pithier, you could suggest _"Mark carried a gun in his briefcase against the mortal threat"_ or similar.

Comment: I would write "Mark carried a gun in his briefcase for *protection". As written, "for safety reasons" could also mean to keep the gun from getting into the wrong hands (supposing the briefcase is locked, anyway).

Comment: @user3169 "for protection" is a very good suggestion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Protection" is fine", so is "on the chance", but "to be on the safe side" might be more idiomatic: _"Mark carried a gun in his briefcase to be on the safe side."_ But we are doing writing advice here, and I can feel the gods' displeasure gathering,,,

Answer (score 5):

There are many, many ways to express the idea that the gun is brought along in case he faced some danger. The simplest of these is

> Mark carried a gun as a precaution.

You'll still have to explain what the danger was, but you'd have to do that anyway with your other constructions.

Comment: +1 Although, depending on how the context is written into the story, the simplest way might be *Mark carried a gun (in his briefcase)*. Saying even *as a precaution* could be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use [just in case](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/just+in+case) which means

> in the event that (something happens).

especially when the "hero" never needed to use the gun.

[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002]

Comment: "for safety reasons" is perfectly acceptable (US) English.  your question is really about style, not language.  He could have written more colorfully "Mark carried a prophylactic Luger in his briefcase", or "Mark packed a lead ventilator in his briefcase", etc.

Comment: sorry that was supposed to be an answer not a comment!